# InvalidStackOperation for input

Tags: transactions, nbitcoin

I've been trying to transfer BTC to another address but can't seem to get the transaction right.

My address is https://www.blockchain.com/btc-testnet/address/mk3RhhbT1pGCtZnoYF856KpdsY1CdTmaNg

```
var network = Network.TestNet
var QBitClient = new QBitNinjaClient(network);

var key = Key.Parse("privateKey", network);

var toAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create("destinationAddress", network);
var fromAddress = BitcoinAddress.Create("address', network);

var balance = QBitClient.GetBalance(fromAddress, unspentOnly: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var coins = balance.Operations
   .SelectMany(op => op.ReceivedCoins)
   .Where(c => c.TxOut.ScriptPubKey == fromAddress.ScriptPubKey)
   .ToList();

var builder = network.CreateTransactionBuilder()
   .AddCoins(coins)
   .SendAll(toAddress)
   .SendFees(new Money(0.0001m, MoneyUnit.BTC))
   .SubtractFees()
   .AddKeys(key);

var trans = builder.BuildTransaction(sign: true);
builder.Verify(trans, new Money(0.0001m, MoneyUnit.BTC), out var error);
```

errors contain
`{Script error on input 0 (InvalidStackOperation)}`
`{Script error on input 1 (InvalidStackOperation)}`

What is wrong with my inputs? They are the first 2 transactions on the address and are all unspent.
Another thing is that the last IN transaction on the address is not picked up by QBitClient.